# Real AttributeGraph Cycle or a Bug?

Tags: swiftui

Simple UI with a slider and a button to disables it using the `.disabled` modifier. Minimal reproducing example with Xcode 14.3.1:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
  @State private var enabled: Bool = true
  @State private var value: Double = 1
  
  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Slider(value: $value, in: 1...100) { _ in }
        .disabled(!self.enabled) // <= note PRESENCE of logical negation
      Button {
        enabled.toggle()
      } label: {
        Text(enabled ? "Disable" : "Enable")
      }
    }
  }
}
```

When the button is clicked I get a stream of `=== AttributeGraph: cycle detected through attribute 348952 ===` errors in Xcode (about 20-ish lines, each with a different ID).

The state name—`enabled`, `disabled`, `paused`, etc.—does not seem to matter.  What matters is the for of the condition for disabling.  With the following expression which does not use logical negation

```swift
  Slider(value: $value, in: 1...100) { _ in }
    .disabled(self.<name>) // <= note ABSENCE of logical negation
```

there are no errors.

I've found I can work around it by choosing whatever naming and avoiding the logical negation operator but I'd like to know if am doing something wrong in principle?

Is this a real error or is it a **bug** somewhere (Xcode, compiler, Swift libraries, or elsewhere)?

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the code is correct and an Xcode/system problem.  On a different machine (M1 vs X86 in the question) with Xcode 14.2 (vs. 14.3.1 in the question) the problem can *not* be reproduced.